# Errors using fclose()

Tags: c

I have a section of code that fails when I try to use `fclose` to close an output file.  The code looks as follows:

```
void WriteArrayForCheck(int numLines, double **Array) {
    char outFile2[300];
    sprintf(outFile2, "OutputArray.txt");
    FILE *outputFile2;
    outputFile2 = fopen(outFile2, "w");
    int incRow;
    for (incRow = 0; incRow < numLines - 1; incRow++) {
         fprintf(outputFile2, "%lf,%lf,%lf\n",
                 Array[incRow][1], Array[incRow][2], Array[incRow][3]);
    }
    fclose(outputFile2);
}
```

I end up with an error related to my executable that says:

```
free(): invalid next size (normal): 0x0000000001ce1710 ***
```

and a whole bunch of other stuff that doesn't make sense...  The ironic thing is if I comment out the line related to `fclose`, then the program does not crash and runs perfectly fine...  I have not had this issue before.  I am sure that my matrices are incremented properly as well.  PLease let me know what you think.

Comment: You are most likely overwriting memory somewhere else in some code you didn't show here. Show especiually the code that calls `WriteArrayForCheck`. Read this: [mcve]

Comment: "and a whole bunch of other stuff that doesn't make sense": maybe they do not make sense to you, but they could help us understanding the problem.

Comment: Two things: that isn't irony, and _and a whole bunch of other stuff that doesn't make sense_ - please include that.

Comment: Not directly related to your problem, but you can simply write:: `outputFile2 = fopen("OutputArray.txt", "w");` and drop the first line of your function alltogether.

Comment: Try running your code through valgrind.  If you're not handling memory correctly (which is what the error suggests) it should tell you where.

Comment: Indexes 1,2,3 are suspicious.  I'd expect 0,1,2.

Comment: printf %p out the file pointer just after you open the file and again just before the close.  Are the values the same?  (no, 'cos your code in between splatted the pointer:)

Comment: How are you *calling* this function?  Especially, how do you declare and initialize the second argument?

Comment: I haven't spotted an obvious issue that would cause `fclose()` to fail. However, you should always check the return value of `fopen()` before attempting any operation on the file pointer returned by `fopen()`.

Comment: You caused heap corruption earlier in the program and it is showing up at this point

Answer (score 2):

The code as posted does not seem to have an obvious problem.

Note however that:

- You should always check the return value of `fopen()` and report failure instead of risking undefined behavior by passing `NULL` to `fprintf` and/or `fclose`.
- You should simplify the first few statements as `FILE *outputFile2 = fopen("OutputArray.txt", "w");`
- If you do something more complicated to compute the filename, post it as the problem may lie in seemingly harmless code that you omitted.
- The `fprintf` conversion specifier for `double` is `%f`, the `l` modifier is useless and ignored in this context. It is required in `fscanf()` to distinguish between `float` and `double`, but not needed in `fprintf` because `float` values are always passed as `double` to variable argument functions.
- The index values `1`, `2` and `3` might be incorrect, arrays are `0` based in C.
- Stopping the loop at `incRow < numLines - 1` is unexpected too, why omit the last row of the matrix? If you really mean it, a comment would be helpful to clarify why.